# Avoid dropdown collaps in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/circuitlego/9dU2y/ where I want to make a dropdown sign in panel.  The issue is that whenever I click on one of the toggle buttons, the dropdown closes.  I've tried a couple of solutions I found online, but then they make the toggle buttons not function.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand"><a href="#">Fiddle</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="signInDropdown" class="btn-group navbar-right">
      <button type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right dropdown-toggle">Sign in<span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" id="emailInput" placeholder="email address" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" id="passwordInput" placeholder="password" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div id="signInInput" data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group btn-group-xs btn-group-justified form-group">
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                  <input type="radio" />Student
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                  <input type="radio" />Fellow
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-default">
                  <input type="radio" />Coordinator
              </label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Sign In</button>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent in jquery

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/9dU2y/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Handles menu drop down
    $('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

> **update answer**

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/P8C74/

Comment: The toggle buttons don't stay selected.  This is one of the approaches I had tried.

Comment: @circuitlego you mean `Button groups` ?

Comment: Yes the buttons in the button group that should act as radio buttons.

Comment: @circuitlego please check the update answer link. let me know if this code not working we can use javascript if still not working on your code

Comment: I'm literally copy pasting your code into my environment and its not working.

Comment: @circuitlego I have another solution for you. what I used on my on going project http://athimannil.com/room/. I will update the answer after my work

Answer (score 0):

Include a `li='dropdown'` before the form..

```
<ul id="signInDropdown" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
      <button type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn dropdown-toggle">Sign in<span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      ...
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/122824